# Проблема при изменении иерархии

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть такая иерархия классов: `Window->baseMaker->someMaker`.

При этом в `baseMaker` есть конструктор, которой принимает параметр `Window`.
Проблема заключается в том, что при определении конструктора

```
public someMaker(Window win):base(win)
```

Вызывается конструктор не `baseMaker`, а конструктор `Window`.

Comment: По-моему, вы пошли не той дорогой. Используйте `UserControl`, которые можно отображать (менять одно с другим) в одном и том же окне или, если очень нужна многооконность, опять же новое окно с нужным `UserControl`.

Comment: Мне нужна иерархия на уровне кода, т.к У каждого someMaker(несколько классов, унаследованных от base maker) будет своя реализация конкретных задач, но все они должны обладать
Возможностью возвращения на окно, из которого был вызван конкретный someMaker

Но не могу утверждать, что вы не правы, я только только начал разбираться с wpf)

Comment: Граф.часть, т.е. интерфейс всегда нужно отделять от остальной логики приложения, а не жестко связывать одно с другим, как вы пытаетесь похоже сделать. Почитайте про MVVM.

Comment: Сейчас займусь, спасибо)

Comment: *Вызывается конструктор не baseMaker, а конструктор Window.* — с чего вы взяли?

Comment: Потому что он просит аргументы для конструктора Window, а не vaseMaker